# Why doesnt my code end

Tags: python, tuples, infinite-loop, function-composition

it suppose to be function composition.
I think that the problem is when there is only one function left in funcs. I wanted it to be an empty tuple but it didn't recognize it like that and enters an infinity loop

Thank you! :)

```
def compose(*funcs):
    if len(funcs)==0:
        return lambda x:x
    f=funcs[0]
    return lambda x: f(compose(funcs[1:])(x))
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 6):

Your `compose` function is defined to use `*args`. Which means that when called in your lambda expression, it always takes one argument and the `funcs` list is never empty. Which is why it recurses endlessly.

You want to either change the definition to `def compose(funcs)` (recommended), or call it with `compose(*funcs[1:])`.

Comment: However I'm not sure I understood currectly, why does the funcs list is never empty..?

Comment: Because of `*args`. When you define a function such as `def compose(*args)` and call it with `compose(funcs[1:])`, the `args` variable becomes `(funcs[1:],)`, which means that it's never empty. If `funcs[1:]` is an empty list, `args = ([],)`. That is, a tuple containing one element (which is an empty list).

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs for more info on `*args` and `**kwargs`.